# Detecting duplicate logins in Symfony's FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

i'm using the FOSUserBundle in my Symfony project and i need to remove duplicate logins. If a user logs in from a different system, I want his/her other session to be disconnected.

Can you please help me on my way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The easy way:*

Map an `activeSessionId` field to your `User` class:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="fos_user")
 */
class User extends BaseUser
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    protected $activeSessionId;

    public function loginWithSessId($sessionId)
    {
        $this->activeSessionId = $sessionId;
    }

    public function logout()
    {
        $this->activeSessionId = null;
    }

    public function getActiveSessId()
    {
        return $this->activeSessionId;
    }
}
```

Then listen to the [security.interactive_login](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/security/authentication.html#security-events) event that will be fired every time the user log in, and save a reference of the session id together with the user:

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\SecurityEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class LoginListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            SecurityEvents::INTERACTIVE_LOGIN => 'onSecurityInteractiveLogin',
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $session = $event->getRequest()->getSession();

        $user->loginWithSessId($session->getId());
        $this->userManager->updateUser($user);
    }
}
```

You can then register the listener with:

```
<service id="app_bundle.security.login_listener" class="AppBundle\Security\LoginListener">
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
</service>
```

or

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app_bundle.security.login_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Security\LoginListener
        arguments: ['@fos_user.user_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Now that your `User` entity know which session is the last one, you can creare a listener to the `security.authentication.success` event, and check if the current session id match with the last active one. If it doesn't, then it's not an active session anymore.

```
namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\AuthenticationEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserManagerInterface;

class AuthenticationListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $requestStack;
    private $userManager;

    public function __construct(RequestStack $requestStack, UserManagerInterface $userManager)
    {
        $this->requestStack = $requestStack;
        $this->userManager = $userManager;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            AuthenticationEvents::AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS => 'onAuthenticationSuccess',
        );
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(AuthenticationEvent $event)
    {
        $token = $event->getAuthenticationToken();
        $sessionId = $this->requestStack->getMasterRequest()->getSession()->getId();
        $activeSessId = $token->getUser()->getActiveSessId();

        if ($activeSessId && $sessionId !== $activeSessId) {
            $token->setAuthenticated(false); // Sets the authenticated flag.
        }
    }
}
```

Finally:

```
<service id="app_bundle.security.auth_listener" class="AppBundle\Security\AuthenticationListener">
    <argument type="service" id="request_stack"/>
    <argument type="service" id="fos_user.user_manager"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" />
</service>
```

or

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app_bundle.security.auth_listener:
        class: AppBundle\Security\AuthenticationListener
        arguments: ['@request_stack', '@fos_user.user_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

Comment: done - but you should not copy/paste this. Try to understand what this does, and then write your implementation. This should just give you an idea of what you can do.

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Ipirani\PanelBundle\Security\AuthenticationListener::onAuthenticationSuccess() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent, instance of Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Event\AuthenticationEvent given

Comment: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Ipirani\PanelBundle\Security\AuthenticationListener::__construct() must be an instance of Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack, instance of FOS\UserBundle\Doctrine\UserManager given, called in E:\WampDeveloper\Websites\ipiraninew.local\webroot\var\cache\prod\appProdDebugProjectContainer.php on line 318 and defined

Comment: Now is Error: Call to a member function getActiveSessId() on string

Comment: when user is not login how to get sessionid
```$activeSessId = $token->getUser()->getActiveSessId();```

Comment: Please help me, I do not understand the issue

Answer (score 0):

Well, I guess, it is possible but not out of box and requires some amount of tweaking.

Let's break down the problem to tiny bits:

1. Session management driver

   You need to set session management driver to DB. This could be any sort of DBMS (e.g. `MySQL`). This ensures your session can be queried upon.
2. Username column

   By default, session tracking DB table does not include the username column. You need to `ALTER TABLE` in order to add the `username`. Make sure it's `NULL`-able, otherwise `Symfony` will not be able to write sessions at all.
3. Login success handler

   Define login success handler for your firewall (within `security.yml`). That handler needs to:

   - extract current session id
   - update the record in DB table with currently logged in user
   - execute `DELETE FROM <session_table> WHERE username = <username> AND session_id != <current_session_id>`

I might have missed something, but roughly, this is it.

Hope it helps you to actually write your own solution,